# Convert GeoJSON file into sql

Tags: mysql, sql, geojson

I want to convert a geojson file into a sql one.
I don't know how to proceed.
In fact, I have all my markers into a geojson which i want to convert into
an SQL script. Then i will access it using a REST API.
My GeoJson looks like this :

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        2.35567957,
        48.8298227
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "name": "140 avenue d'Italie à Paris"
    }
  }
 ]
}
```

Using https://sqlizer.io, it gives me :

```
CREATE TABLE Markers (
`type` VARCHAR(17) CHARACTER SET utf8,
`features_type` VARCHAR(7) CHARACTER SET utf8,
`features_geometry_type` VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET utf8,
`features_geometry_coordinates` NUMERIC(10, 8),
`features_properties_name` VARCHAR(27) CHARACTER SET utf8);
INSERT INTO Markers VALUES 
('FeatureCollection','Feature','Point',2.35567957,NULL);
INSERT INTO Markers VALUES 
('FeatureCollection','Feature','Point',48.8298227,'140 avenue d''Italie 
à Paris');
```

Which is not correct.
How can I proceed to get something that i could use later as a geojson base ?

Thanks for your answer !
I hope this is enough detailed !

Comment: did you ever get this resolved? I have same issue. How to add both the properties of a geojson file AND the coordinates into a single table.